# Problema na execução do Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Amigos, preciso da ajuda de vocês para resolver um problema.

Quando abro o Android Studio aparece o seguinte erro e não consigo fazer nada diante disso.

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

***>Failed to resolve:com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+***

Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Se você utiliza o Android Studio 3.0, adicione `google()` como repositório no Gradle.

Comment: Amigo,obrigado pela ajuda.No entanto,sou iniciante não sei como proceder.Poderia me explicar como adicionar no repositório ?

Comment: Se possível poste o código de seu gradle

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.leomastra.primeiroprojeto"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
 }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione a dependência com a versão completa:

```
dependencies { 
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

E no gradle (app):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

Depois basta sincronizar o projeto.